# Is there a more elegant way to do conditional cumulative sums in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build a little portfolio app and calculate what my average entry price is and realised gains off the back of that. Here's what I have so far which works but curious to know if there's a more elegant way to get conditional cumulative sums without creating extra columns. Seems like a lot of steps for effectively a sumifs statement in excel.

Input dataframe:

```py
    hist_pos = pd.DataFrame(data=[
        [datetime(2020, 5, 1), 'PPT.AX', 30, 20.00, 15.00, 'Buy'],
        [datetime(2020, 5, 2), 'RIO.AX', 25, 25.00, 15.00, 'Buy'],
        [datetime(2018, 5, 3), 'BHP.AX', 100, 4.00, 15.00, 'Buy'],
        [datetime(2019, 5, 3), 'BHP.AX', 50, 4.00, 15.00, 'Sell'],
        [datetime(2019, 12, 3), 'PPT.AX', 80, 4.00, 15.00, 'Buy'],
        [datetime(2020, 5, 3), 'RIO.AX', 100, 4.00, 15.00, 'Buy'],
        [datetime(2020, 5, 5), 'PPT.AX', 50, 40.00, 15.00, 'Sell'],
        [datetime(2020, 5, 10), 'PPT.AX', 15, 45.00, 15.00, 'Sell'],
        [datetime(2020, 5, 18), 'PPT.AX', 30, 20.00, 15.00, 'Sell']],
        columns=['Date', 'Ticker', 'Quantity', 'Price', 'Fees', 'Direction'])
```

Code base:

```py
    hist_pos.sort_values(['Ticker', 'Date'], inplace=True) 
    hist_pos.Quantity = pd.to_numeric(hist_pos.Quantity) #convert to number

    # where direction is sale, make quantity negative
    hist_pos['AdjQ'] = np.where(
                hist_pos.Direction == 'Buy', 1, -1)*hist_pos.Quantity
    #Sum quantity to get closing quantity for each ticker using the AdjQ column
    hist_pos['CumQuan'] = hist_pos.groupby('Ticker')['AdjQ'].cumsum()
```

Expected Output:

```py
  Date        Ticker  Quantity  Price  Fees Direction  AdjQ  CumQuan
2 2018-05-03  BHP.AX       100    4.0  15.0       Buy   100      100
3 2019-05-03  BHP.AX        50    4.0  15.0      Sell   -50       50
4 2019-12-03  PPT.AX        80    4.0  15.0       Buy    80       80
0 2020-05-01  PPT.AX        30   20.0  15.0       Buy    30      110
6 2020-05-05  PPT.AX        50   40.0  15.0      Sell   -50       60
7 2020-05-10  PPT.AX        15   45.0  15.0      Sell   -15       45
8 2020-05-18  PPT.AX        30   20.0  15.0      Sell   -30       15
1 2020-05-02  RIO.AX        25   25.0  15.0       Buy    25       25
5 2020-05-03  RIO.AX       100    4.0  15.0       Buy   100      125
```

The code above works fine and produces the expected output for column CumQuan. However, I have broader code (here in [Repl](https://repl.it/repls/NecessaryDarkgreyForms)) where I need to go through this process a number of times for various columns. So wondering if there was a simpler way to process the data to use group by, cumulative sum with a conditional.

Comment: I would suggest you to ask one question and show your expected output on that particular problem. Right now there is a lot of steps going on without clear explanations.

Comment: Thanks - have edited to make it simpler. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping together is the only thing I can think of.

```
hist_pos2 = hist_pos.groupby('Ticker').agg(CumQuan=('AdjQ','cumsum'), CumCost=('CFBuy','cumsum'))

CumQuan CumCost
2   100 -415.0
3   50  -415.0
4   80  -335.0
0   110 -950.0
6   60  -950.0
7   45  -950.0
8   15  -950.0
1   25  -640.0
5   125 -1055.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely makes the cumulative sum formulas cleaner. Shame there's no way to add some conditionality into the formulas. Was messing around with apply functions but it got quite messy.